# encrypted en base64encoded string not same in database

Tags: php, encryption, pdo, mariadb, livecode

i've read a lot of posts concerning similair problem with utf-8 issues and tried some too but i can't find the cause.

I'm using livecode and i want to encrypt some strings to a database. So i encrypt in Livecode then base64encode then send to database via PHP/PDO.
encrypt-->base64encode-->base64decode-->decrypt within livecode works ok.

Now when i send the base64encoded data to the MariaDB database it saves it, except + has become a space.
The database, table and columns are all utf8mb4_unicode_ci.
If i change the space to + manually via phpmyadmin in the database and read out with Livecode then it base64decodes-->decrypts correct!

This are the php files i use to connect and update the db:

```
<?php
// the connect.php file
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "blabla";
$password = "blabla";

try {
    //$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=blabla",$username, $password);
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=blabla;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
    //$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=blabla;charset=utf8mb4", $username, $password,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'"));
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //echo "Connected successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

you can see i tried some charsets in the connect file also

```
<?php
//this is the file to update the DB
require_once 'connect.php';
//
try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE tabel_users SET user=:user,
    password=:password, email=:email, userlevel=:userlevel WHERE
    id_user=:id_user");
    $stmt->bindParam(':id_user', $_POST['id_user'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':userlevel', $_POST['userlevel'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    //$stmt->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    //$stmt->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    //$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    //$stmt->bindParam(':userlevel', $_POST['userlevel'], PDO::PARAM_LOB);
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();

    if($stmt->execute()) { echo "Ge-update informatie verzonden naar de
    database!"; } else { echo "Failure!"; };

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Not updated: " . $e->getMessage();
}

//var_dump($_POST)
$db = NULL;

?>
```

Also tried PDO::PARAM_LOB
Tried VARCHAR  VARBIN BLOB but this did not change a thing.

My first guess was that Livecode does something weird while posting it to the php file. But checking the variable just before it is send has the + in the string to send. So i don't really get it where it goes wrong.

Comment: Just a note of caution. Storing passwords encrypted in your database is always a bad idea! What you should store is a one way salted hash of the passwords. There is also a new messageDigest coming in LC9 that will allow more secure hashes as both md5 and sha1 is too weak for today's number crunching computers.

Comment: Why is the encrypted password in a database a bad idea? Yes i know the new messageDigest is coming, it was shifted from dp6 to dp7. So have to wait a little more.

Comment: Ok did some more reading about hashing instead of encrypting the password, it's a one way solution, as you can't "de-hash" it.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is not with the database it is that php is url decoding your base64 string, that will convert '+' to ' ' (plus to space). You need to urlencode your password parameter before posting it. Here's the LiveCode doc for [URLEncode](https://livecode.com/resources/api/#livecode_script/urlencode).

It depends on the content type of your post as explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data/4073451#4073451).

Comment: By the way, i forgot to mention, Updating the table directly from Livecode (without PHP files in between) then it works correct. But i need some others to use it too

Comment: Yes! This seems to work just great!  --> Encrypt-->Base64Encode-->URLEncode (within Livecode) --> Post to DB via PHP/PDO. Then Get from DB via PHP/PDO --> (URLDecode not used) -->Base64Decode-->Decrypt.   When i use URLDecode in LC then it is not working ok, without URLdecode it is OK. Thank you all!

Comment: The reason is probably that you're basically submitting a web form to PHP. Web forms escape spaces as +. So if you want to transmit a "+", you need to URL-encode it to %2B, which won't accidentally be converted to a space.

Comment: indeed i added URLEncode as you can see in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but going from PHP to livecode and I got as far as concluding that the problem was with php encryption vs livecode encryption.  if you try base encoding without encryption they will play nice.  I don't have an answer for it though, but I remember the experts saying its got to do with the "header" of the encrypted binary.  ideally i would like to see an answer to this problemnas I ended up going without encryption to get around it.

Comment: Please see my solution above, i added URLEncode after base64Encode, but i did not use URLDecode before base64decode. This way it is Encrypted, base64encoded and URLEncoded. It then works correct. Did several tests now, and all ok.

Answer (score -1):

When I use base64 encoding to share data with another system （javascript）I always use this code after encoding:

Replace space with empty in tEncodedData.

LC adds spaces for base64encode. It works fine when I remove them.